# No comma preceding quote from a document?

Tags: commas

I am a court reporter, and I was recently informed that I should not put a comma before a quote from a document.  E.g., in the sentence: John said, "We need to clear this item," the comma after "said" is appropriate, but in the sentence: Paragraph 2 says "We need to clear this item," a comma after "says" would be inappropriate.  Anybody else ever hear of that rule?  It's new to me.

Comment: Your [stenotype](http://www.long-live-pitmans-shorthand.org.uk/vocabulary-punctuation.htm) has a comma?

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of this distinction, though it may be upheld in some very specialized style guide for court reporters. For general purposes, the advice in *Chicago Manual of Style*, 15th Edition (2003) is sensible and sufficiently detailed to cover most situations:

> **6.53** *Comma with quoted material.* Quoted material, if brief, is usually introduced by a comma; if longer or more formal, by a colon [citations omitted]. If a quotation is introduced by *that*, *whether*, or a similar conjunction, no comma is needed. [Examples omitted.]
>
> **11.20** *Use of the colon [with introductory phrases].* A formal introductory phrase, such as *thus* or *the following*, is usually followed by a colon. [Example omitted.] Such perfunctory phrases as "Jacqueline Jones writes:" or "The defendant stated:" are often awkward, and sensitive writers avoid them.
>
> **11.21** *Use of the comma [with introductory phrases].* A comma, rather than a colon is often used after *said*, *replied*, *asked*, and similar verbs. [Examples omitted.]

The crucial point here is that Chicago bases its advice about when to use a colon, when to use a comma, and when to use neither on the relationship between the introductory wording and the following quotation, not on whether the source of the quotation is a person or a document.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using a comma, colon, or other mark to introduce the quote.

The argument could be made, however, that the paragraph is not itself **saying** anything. As such, "say" there is not a speech tag, and the quotation is not direct speech. Rather, the quote in that instance is part of the sentence itself. Consider

> Paragraph 2 says (that) "We need to clear this item."

or

> Paragraph 2 outlines the "need to clear this item".

So it could be seen as "inappropriate" to suggest that the paragraph is speaking. It might pay to check whether they would accept a colon instead, eg,

> Paragraph 2 says: "We need to clear this item."

But note that many instances of punctuation are a matter of stylistic preference, so you should go with whatever your employer has deemed right.